# Write a C program to arrange the numbers in an array as a series of odd and even numbers

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

I've made an attempt to create the above program,but there's some error.Here's my program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

void main()
{
    int a[20],o[20],e[20],c[40],i,j,k,l,n;
    printf("enter size of array");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("enter array");
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        for(j=1;j<=n;j++)
        {
            for(k=1;k<=(n-j);k++)
            {
                if(a[i]%2==0)
                {
                    o[j]=a[i];
                    break;
                }
        else
        {
            e[k]=a[i];
        }
        }
        }
    }
    for(i=1;i<=j;i++)
    {
        c[l]=o[i];
    }
    for(i=1;i<=k;i++)
    {
        c[l+k]=e[k];
    }
    printf("The new array is");
    for(l=1;l<=(j+k);l++)
    {
        printf(" %d ",c[l]);
    }
    getch();
}
```

Can anybody please help me rectify the error in the above program?Can someone also give me a few tips on how to become a good C programmer?

Comment: "Some error"? We don't know what it is.

Comment: none of your arrays are properly initialized BTW.

Comment: `for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }`  --> looks like OP thinks the first element is `a[1]`, when it should be `a[0]`.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Array _initialization_ not needed here.

Comment: "some" is not recognized as an internal or external comand, operable program or batch file

Comment: @chux `o` is set only if some other value is even.

Comment: @EugeneSh. - By 'some error' I meant to say that the program could be run only halfway.

Comment: @Susan If you are going to stick with programming, engineering or any somewhat precise discipline, you should learn to define your problems in a precise and non-ambiguous way. "Some error", "run only halfway" are vague and pretty useless in these terms, as they can mean just anything.

Comment: @EugeneSh.Thank you for your advice,but by 'run only halfway' I meant exactly what I said.Only half the program could be run.The cursor stayed put after that

Comment: `void main` -> `int main`. Fixed ;)

Comment: language-agnostic tip: get to know and learn to love your debugger!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably because you never initialize the variable `l`. 
Using an uninitialized variables yields in *undefined behaviour* (google that).

Also your array indexes start at 1 as for example here:

```
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
```

In C array indexes start at 0, so you should write this:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
```

This appies to all your other `for` loops.

- There may be other problems though.
- Your program looks overly complicated
- Using variable names such as `odd` instead of `o` and `even` instead of `e` would make your program much easier to read.
- Your program is poorly formatted. Correct formatting is essential to readbility

Comment: I've written for(l=1; l<=(j+k); l++)  towards the end..isn't that enough to initialize l?

Comment: No, it's too late, you are using `l` _before_  that `for` loop.